# Recursive function to find if a number is prime or not

Tags: haskell, primes

I need to implement a recursive function that returns 1 if the number is prime or 0 otherwise. The homework problem says that I can't use '%' mod. Haskell should be something like this... I'm not sure.

```
isprime x = prime(x sqrt(x))

prime x i = | i==1 = 1
            | mod(x i)==0 = 0
            | otherwise = prime(x i-1)

mod num div | num<div = n
            | otherwise = mod(num-div div)
```

I tested an algorithm in C because I don't have a Haskell compiler on my Mac, but there's something wrong because it's returning false positive on `primes-1`. idk why.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    int a=0,b=31;
    printf("\n Prime numbers between %d and %d \n",a,b);

    for(int a=0; a<=b; a++){
        if(isPrime(a)==0){
            printf("%d, ",a);
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}

int isPrime(int x){
    return prime(x, sqrt(x));
}

int prime(int x, int i){
    if(i==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(mod(x,i)==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return prime(x, i-1);
    }
}

int mod(int num, int div){
    if(num<div) return num;
    else return mod(num-div, div);
}
```

The algorithm is returning this:

```
Prime numbers between 0 and 31 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 18, 20, 24, 30,
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test

Comment: Search here for `[haskell] test prime` and you'll find you're not the first to be tring this - steal some ideas, decide which are best.

Comment: I can't even start, don't know how recursion works with haskell, I just know how to do the algorithm with plain loops in C `for(int i=2; i<n; i++) {
        if (n%i==0 && i!=n) return false;
    }
    return true;`

Comment: @Vitim.us that isn't a recursive call, but an iterative approach.

Comment: "the problem says that I can't use '%' mod" Please tell me that's a joke. A prime test without using modulus? That's bizarre. Well, unless they meant that `(%)` is not the modulus operator in Haskell and you have to use `mod` (or `rem`).

Comment: I think I'm supposed to write it myself, my `mod` implementation is pretty elegant I think. I can't figure out any other way

Comment: You don't/can't use parentheses to call a function in Haskell, just put the arguments after the function name: e.g. `mod (num - div) div`. The parentheses are only required to group expressions (like `num - div` in my example).

Comment: `mod x b = x - b*div x b` so technically, if you can't use `mod`, perhaps you can't use `div` as well? Also, in Haskell parentheses are for grouping, so you'd call your function as e.g. `mod(num-div) div` or `prime x (i-1)`.

Comment: @dbaupp and Will Ness, you both are right, I'm calling functions wrong, it's just my mind tricking me with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(apparently, there's a new policy regarding homework, viz. ["If you don't want a fully vetted, complete and testable answer, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask - by Tim Post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag#comment421799_147100), so here goes).</sub>

Basically, your code is almost correct (1 is *not* a prime), sans some syntax issues.

```
isprime x = prime x (floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x)   where
  prime x i | i==1 && x > 1  = 1
            | x == i*div x i = 0
            | otherwise      = prime x (i-1)

-- mod x i = x - i*div x i
-- mod x i == 0 = x == i*div x i
```

`fromIntegral` is just some adaptor which lets us use an `Integral` value as an argument to `sqrt` which expects a  `Floating` argument. Try using `:i sqrt` or `:i Integral` etc. at the GHCi prompt (also <s>read some documentation</s> google around).

But algorithmically there's place for improvement. First of all, it's much better to try out the divisors in the other direction, from 2 up to the number's `sqrt`, because any given number is more likely to have a smaller factor than a larger one. Second, after trying out 2, there's no need to try out any other even number as a possible divisor. This gives us

```
isprime x | x == 2          = 1
          | x < 2 || even x = 0
          | otherwise       = go 3
  where
    r = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
    go i | i > r          = 1
         | x == i*div x i = 0        -- really, | rem x i == 0 = 0
         | otherwise      = go (i+2)
```

---

This would normally be written down using `Bool`s, and a higher-order function like `and` which captures the recursions and testing pattern (so it is not recursive anymore):

```
isprime x = if isPrime x then 1 else 0

isPrime x = x==2 || x>2 && odd x && 
              and [rem x d /= 0 | d <- [3,5..floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x]]
```

There's some redundancy in there still: after we've tested by 3, there's no need to test by any of its multiples too (just like we did with 2 and evens). We really just need to test by *prime* factors:

```
isPrime x = x>1 && and 
    [rem x d /= 0 | d <- takeWhile (<= (floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x)) primes]

primes = filter isPrime [2..]
       = 2 : filter isPrime ([3..] `minus` [4,6..])
       = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]
       = 2 : 3 : filter isPrime ([5,7..] `minus` [9,15..])
       = 2 : 3 : 5 : filter isPrime (([7,9..]`minus`[9,15..])`minus`[25,35..])
       ...........
```

Here we see the emergence of the sieve of Eratosthenes, **P** = {3,5, ...} \ **U** {{*p<sup>2</sup>, p<sup>2</sup> + 2p,* ...} | *p* in **P**} (w/out the `2`).

see also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_features#Prime_numbers
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers

Answer (score 5):

Your basic idea is fine. In Haskell you can use lists instead of iteration. Here's what you need to look into:

1. Install and play with ghci.
2. If you have no idea how to do anything in Haskell, visit *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* http://learnyouahaskell.com/
3. List comprehensions. Lean what `[n^2 | n <- [1..10]]` means and play with similar lists.
4. Look up functions like `sqrt` on hoogle http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/
5. Because Haskell is statically typed you will need to convert some numerical types between `Integer` and `Float`. Look up `Float -> Integer` and `Integer -> Float` when you do. **DON'T** use `unsafeCoerce` - it's unsafe and will break things badly.
6. Use hoogle to look up `[Bool] -> Bool`. Why did I suggest that? How would `[Bool]` help, and how would you make one anyway? (Revise list comprehension again.)
7. Come back with more specific questions once you've found out more and had a go.
8. Always start your assignments early, especially if you've missed classes!

You were set this homework not because the department was stuck for a way of deciding whether 102659473841923461 is prime, but because they want you to learn some Haskell. Try not to try to solve the problem without doing the learning - it'll only make the next assignment even harder! (This is why I've resisted the temptation to translate the "pseudocode" in another answer into Haskell.)

Comment: 102659473841923461 = 3 * 79 * 4831 * 89663079463 to save everybody else the trouble :-)

Comment: Excellent advices but I believe that your 6th point requires more knowledge than necessary (if you follow LYH). He may just take advantage of Haskell laziness instead.

Comment: I believe the functions I've sent him to _do_ expliot the laziness of a binary operator to not evaluate the whole list, and I'm surprised you feel 6 is too hard after 2! The point of 5 and 6 is to get used to using Hoogle as a source of information. If he doesn't need my advice when he's worked through 1-5, that's excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Haskell, and I don't want to hand you the answer, but I can offer a method.

if you check all the numbers from 2 to sqrt(n), and none of them are factors of n, then n is prime.

So maybe a function call with the following pseudo code might work:

```
def isPrime(n):
   return isPrimeHelper(n,sqrt(n))

def isPrimeHelper(n,counter):
   if counter == 1 return True
   if n % counter == 0 return False
   else return isPrime(n,counter-1)
```